# Migrate Struts 1 tags to Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, taglib

I am trying to reuse bunch of JSPs from Struts1 to Struts2, some of the JSP have taglibs declared as below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
```

When I change them to:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="bean"%>
```

I get an error:

> JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /jsp/survey/surveyIdPreview.jsp:
>   /jsp/survey/surveyIdPreview.jsp(27,1) --> JSPG0046E: Unable to locate tagfile for tag html

The reason I am using the same taglib thrice is because the tags are sprinkled across the JSPs and I am trying to minimize the code changes.

This approach works for the remaining of the application but for some pages I see the above error.
I'm not able to understand why the TLD within Struts2 jar is not visible to some pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 3 is for struts 1 tags.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
```

Struts 2 uses only a single tld, the struts-tags.tld.
So you can only declare it as :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

Also make sure, you struts2-core-2.x.x.jar in your WEB-INF/lib